# psexec and process.start, waitforexit

Tags: .net, vb.net, psexec

Task : copy file from remote pc to remote pc using admin account

code :

```
    psi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    psi.Arguments = ParaStr
    psi.UserName = StrUserID
    psi.Password = ConvertToSecureString(txtAdminPassword.Text)
    psi.Domain = StrDomain
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    psi.UseShellExecute = False
    Dim proc As New Process
    proc.StartInfo = psi
    proc.Start()
```

ParaStr= /k psexec.exe -h /user AdminUser \SourceMachine  cmd /c Copy  \sourcepc\file1 \destpc\folder

so when executing command, it prompts for admin password , once verified , it copies the file and end

this is working fine

i want to check when the actual copy work is done (the files size is unknown and so sometime it takes more then 3/4 hrs)

i keep the cmd window open to see if the process is over, it will return the message that task was completed or it failed in command prompt

how can i check through the VB , when the process is over ?

Answer (score 2):

On the console application you can set Process Exit code and check the same on parent calling process and based on Exit code you can decide it was success of not

```
you can return it from Main if you declare your Main method to return an int, or call Environment.Exit(code)
```

To check exit code

```
 p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("RegSvr32");
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();

        return p.ExitCode;
```

Comment: thanx for a Quick reply, it works, but still i have to keep checking the command prompt and Proc.ExitCode only gets triggered if i close the cmd

Comment: or how can i capture the result ie.             


1 file(s) copied.
cmd exited on xyzpc with error code 0

Comment: i didnot understand that completely... p.WaitForExit(); should wait for cmd to exit or you close it.

Comment: You can change the code on cmd application?? if so you have many ways to do this. You can use any of the IPC(Inter Process Communication to do that)

Comment: Sumeet, This what it does.... , When i run it it opens the command prompt and waits for me to input the admin password (psexec -h /user AdminUser), once the i supply that , it starts the copy command and returns with copy command result .i.e. - File copied followed by psexec result.   so my Q was how can i check if copy command or psexec command is over.   If i use  StandardOutput , prompt will not appear and i don't want to supply the password in plain text with psexec -p

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/6dca867b-0881-4ff9-b336-d03761df0377

You should be able to capture the `StandardOutput` once the process is complete. That should give you success/failure. Then its all about how you want to handel the process completion event in your VB app that's starting the process.

Comment: We normally expect more then just a link when answering questions.  It doesn't appear that ANY of the code contained in that thread would result in the task the author wants to solve.